# I want to download whole webpage when i click button

Tags: android, file, url, save

This is my code it can save only html but when i click button my app crashes..! my questions are

- when i click button my app crashes..why?
- is there anyway that i can save complete webpage for offline view plz help

  ```
          public void onClick(View view) {
                      download();         
      }
  });
          }
          public void download()
          {
      try {
  //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
  //this is the file to be downloaded
  URL url = new URL("http://somewhere.com");
  //create the new connection
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  //set up some things on the connection
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
      urlConnection.connect();`

  //set the path where we want to save the file
  //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
  //sd card.
  File SDCardRoot = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
  //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
  //which we want to save the file as.
  File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"somefile.txt");

  //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
  FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

  //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
  InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

  //this is the total size of the file
  int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
  //variable to store total downloaded bytes
  int downloadedSize = 0;
  //create a buffer...
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer*emphasized text*
  //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
  while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
      //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
      fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
      //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
      downloadedSize += bufferLength;
      //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
      //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

  }
  //close the output stream when done
  fileOutput.close();
  ```

  //catch some possible errors...
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

**Log cat:**

```
07-13 13:16:33.174: I/Choreographer(791): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-13 13:16:33.274: D/gralloc_goldfish(791): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-13 13:16:33.405: I/Choreographer(791): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-12 12:14:40.053: D/AndroidRuntime(791): Shutting down VM
07-12 12:14:40.053: W/dalvikvm(791): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.breeze.http.MainActivity.download(MainActivity.java:54)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.breeze.http.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-12 12:14:40.083: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the network request on main ui thread which isn't allowed. Use an AsyncTask.

As to why Android blocks this : You are trying to download some html content from the internet on button click. But if you do this whole process on the main thread, the ui will become unresponsive (E.g buttons won't work) until the network request is complete.

This has a good sample code to use it : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Edit 1 :

As to how to download the source of an html page :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url); //Replace url with your own url. 
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

Comment: thanks.. Do you how to download source files of the website being saved?? like chrome does..!

Comment: Check edit. Just use this code inside the doInBackground() method of the asynctask.

Comment: No man, sorry. We can help you out with specific problems but we can't write the whole code for you.